# What's the meaning of "uniformly bounded from below"?

Tags: complex-analysis, terminology

[image: Stein142]

This picture is from Stein's Complex Analysis.

What's the meaning of "uniformly bounded from below"?

Comment: Bounded from below by a constant that's universal for whole of $K$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that there is a constant $K>0$ such that, for every $n\in\mathbb N$ and every $z\in\Omega$, $\bigl\lvert G_n(z)\bigr\rvert\geqslant K$.